Brownian martingale example
I'm reading A First Course in Stochastic Calculus by Louis-Pierre Arguin and am wanting clarify my understanding of Example 5.30 on page 122, specifically the use of Corollaries 5.15 and 5.18.
I'll provide the context so that notation is (hopefully) understood and then get to the example and my queries on it.
We are applying Itô’s formula to a function $f(t, x)$ of both time and space:
$f : [0, T] \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$
$(t, x) \rightarrow f(t, x)$
The following notation for the partial derivatives is used:
$\partial_0f(t, x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t, x)$
$\partial_1f(t, x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, x)$
$\partial^2_1f(t, x) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t, x)$
Corollary 5.29 (Brownian martingales). Let $(B_t, t \leq T)$ be a standard Brownian motion.
Consider $f \in \mathcal{C}^{1,2}([0, T] × \mathbb{R})$ such that the process $({\partial_1 f(t, B_t)}, t \leq T) \in \mathcal{L}^2_c(T)$. Then the process $(f(t,B_t) - \int_{0}^{t}\{\partial_0 f(s, B_s) + \frac{1}{2}\partial^2_1 f(s, B_s)\}ds, t \leq T)$ is a martingale for the Brownian filtration.
Corollary 5.18 (Wiener integral). Let $(B_t, t \leq T)$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $f : [0, T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\int_{0}^{T}f^2(s) ds \lt \infty$. Then the process $(\int_{0}^{t}f(s) dB_s, t \leq T)$ is Gaussian.
Corollary 5.15. Let $(B_t, t \leq T)$ be a standard Brownian motion, and let $X \in \mathcal{L}^2_c(T)$. We have ${\bf E}[(\int_{0}^{t}X_sdB_s)(\int_{0}^{t'}X_sdB_s)] = \int_{0}^{t \wedge t'}{\bf E}[X^2_s]ds, t, t' \leq T$
Example 5.30. Consider the function $f(t, x) = tx$. In this case, we have ${\partial f}_0 = x$, ${\partial f}_1 = t$, and $\partial^2_1 f = 0$. Itô's formula yields $d(_) =  d_ + _ d$.
Therefore, the process $_ = _ − \int_{0}^{t} _ d$ is a martingale for the Brownian filtration. It is also a Gaussian process by Corollary 5.18. The mean is 0 and the covariance is by Corollary 5.15 ${\bf E}[M_tM_{t'}] = \int_{0}^{t \wedge t'} s^2 ds = \frac{(t \wedge t')^3}{3}$
Questions:
#1. I understand the use of Corollary 5.15 for the covariance if the $X$ referenced there equals ${\partial_1 f(t, B_t)}$. This would mean we have $t$ plugged in for $X$ and the expectation of $t^2$ would be $t^2$ and the integral would come out. I came to this conclusion based on the statement $({\partial_1 f(t, B_t)}, t \leq T) \in \mathcal{L}^2_c(T)$ in Corollary 5.29 matching $X \in \mathcal{L}^2_c(T)$ in Corollary 5.15. Is that correct? If not, how is Corollary 5.15 used?
#2. I don't understand how Corollary 5.18 (again I'm trying to pattern match) shows that $M_t$ is Gaussian? What does the $f$ referenced there match to in the Example given the $f$ in the Example is a function of space and time and the $f$ in 5.18 is a function of time alone? I can only guess it would be ${\partial_1 f(t, B_t)}$ once again and the connection would be made by seeing that $\int_{0}^{T}t^2 ds \lt \infty$. Is that correct? If not, would appreciate clarification.

#1. Hint $M_t=\int_0^t s,dB_s,.$ What is $X_s$ here? #2. The hint for #1 should answer the second question. Advice: don't do pattern match. Learn what those theorems mean regardless of their notation. Edit. I don't know where you have that Corollary 5.18 from. I expect it to say that $\int_0^t\color{red}{f(s)},dB_s$ is Gaussian, not $\int_0^tf^2(s),dB_s,.$

Apologies in advance @KurtG and thanks for your time, however I don't follow how you derived your expression for $M_t$ from that in the Example. I'm known to be particularly thick on occasion. My bad on 5.18, have corrected.

Hint: $dM_t$ appears in an equation you already wrote down: $d(tB_t) = t,dB_t + B_t, dt,.$

Cheers @KurtG, much appreciated.
